# In JavaScript/jQuery, is there a shorter way of writing an 'if' statement with many OR's on the same tested variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that to declare more than one variable, there is a shortcut like `var x=1,y=2,z=3`.

Now, if I have an `if` statement where I test ONE variable, but for many values, like that:

```
if (x==1 || x==15 || x==25 || x==150){

}
```

Since the `x` is going to be something much longer in a real life example, I want to find a shortcut to enumerate all those values, one behind another, without writing the name of the variable every time)

How can I do it?

Comment: I presume you meant to compare the values instead of assigning.

Comment: var x = my.really.long.name.I.dont.want.to.continue.to.rewrite;

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Yes I could use `var x=..` but just wanted to see if there is a syntax shortcut for if statements. Regards

Comment: [jsPerf performance comparison](http://jsperf.com/if-statement-with-many-ors) -- if performance is your concern, you're probably best off sticking with your original `if (x==1) || ... )` approach.

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger for that link. I will use it to test my code. Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use inArray and do this (cross browser compatible)

```
if(jQuery.inArray(x,[1,15,125,150]) > -1)
{
}
```

Comment: It's true but the naming of this function is unfortunately so bad that even you forgot that it doesn't return a boolean. And anytime I type `.inArray` I would forget it as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Does this work for old version of IE too? If it is, I don't understand why indexOf is still used..

Comment: @eric01 because you can use the [`indexOf`-shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) to make it work in IE and get a sensible API as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array of possible values and test to see if the variable occurs in it.

```
if ([1, 15, 25, 150].indexOf(x) > -1) {
```

This isn't supported by IE8 and earlier though. See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which includes a work around for old browsers.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response. I am looking into it. Regards

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered a case-switch statement? Not very gimmicky, but underused and easy to read, and it's portable to most other programming languages:

```
switch (x) {
case 1:
case 15:
case 25:
case 150:
  // do something
  break;
}
```

If you're concerned about performance, I ran a [jsPerf test case](http://jsperf.com/if-statement-with-many-ors) and this technique was the fastest in Chrome.

Comment: This wouldn't really accomplish the same thing though.  The if clause is stating that the following code should be executed only under the circumstances that at least one of the conditions is true.  The switch statement would instead execute different code entirely unless the same statements were copied to each case, making the switch longer and less efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, but: Anything you put in place of `//do something` will be run for all of the `case`s above it (but below the last `break`). [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Yhuwr/).

Comment: Sorry, on account of this being an example, I didn't notice the cases fell through. I guess that's why it's not a generally recommended approach (http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/25/id-rather-switch-than-fight/).  I was merely referring to logical disjunctions though (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of items to check for, then a map (using a JavaScript object) can be tidy and works in all browsers:

```
var items = {1:true, 15:true, 25:true, 150:true};
if (items[x] === true) {
    // Found x in items
}
```

For larger numbers of items, a map is a more efficient lookup mechanism than the other examples that linearly search an array.

I also find it a lot simpler code to maintain than a multiline `if` statement.

Comment: @Blazemonger - I overwrote your edit because the `=== true` is important in this case because the object can have other properties or methods that I do NOT want this comparison to be able to match.  For example, if x was "keys" or "create" or any string that matches an existing method or property on a javascript object, then your edit would allow the comparison to pass, but it won't pass with the `=== true` in place.

Answer (score 0):

[UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) has a .any function:

```
var testArray = [1,15,125,150];
if (_.any(testArray, function (item) { return item === x; })) {
  // do stuff
}
```

The library has lots of great features for dealing with arrays.